# The while loop should end after reading the third line in my file but why does it run the fourth time?

Tags: c++, function, file, while-loop, eof

```
void Load_from_file()
    {
        ifstream fin("Data.txt");
        //fin.open("Data.txt");
        if (!fin.is_open())
            cout << "Error while opening the file" << endl;
        else
        {
            int f_id;
            int u_id;
            int priority;
            char acc_type;
            char delim;
            while (!fin.eof())
            {
                
                fin >> f_id;
                fin >> delim; // skipping the comma
                fin >> u_id;
                fin >> delim;
                fin >> priority;
                fin >> delim;
                fin >> acc_type;
            }
            fin.close();
        }
    }
```

---

Data in the file is :

7551,10,3,R
25551,3,10,W
32451,4,7,R

---

*The while loop should end after third iteration but it terminates after fourth iteration*

Comment: Change `while (!fin.eof())` to `while(fin >> f_id >> delim >> u_id >> delim >> priority >> delim >> acc_type) {/*do something with the data...?*/}`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes i get something from that but i am unable to figure out the solution to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the condition in the while statement

```
        while (!fin.eof())
        {
            
            fin >> f_id;
            fin >> delim; // skipping the comma
            fin >> u_id;
            fin >> delim;
            fin >> priority;
            fin >> delim;
            fin >> acc_type;
        }
```

The condition fin.eof() can occur within the body of the while loop after already reading the last data.

Either you need to write

```
        while (fin >> f_id >> delim >> u_id >> delim >>
               priority >> delim >> acc_type );
```

Or it would be much better to read a whole line and then using the string stream to enter various data like

```
while ( std::getline( fin, line ) )
{
    std::istringstream iss( line );
    
    iss >> f_id;
    // and so on
}
```